# C# how to implement a termination handler

Tags: c#

I want to serialise an object in C# if a user stops a console application.
I have seen various questions dealing with this, but no final answer.
I will need to catch Ctrl+c, clicking the top right corner and stop process from the task manager.
Is it safe if I have an implementation object and add this as a finalizer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this forum you can find an example of exit event detection. Hope this can help you.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/707e9ae1-a53f-4918-8ac4-62a1eddb3c4a/

Comment: Best answer, but I still have not managed to handle all different termination possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Just handle [`AppDomain.ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx).